# Appointment objects from read binary file has included class name and curly brackets in printed string

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a simple Java GUI application that reads objects from a binary file.
My model class for appointment contains properties - name, day and hour.

However, when I read the file the output printed in dialogue box is

> Appointment{day=Mark,hour=24,name=6}

This is not what I want, as it has included firstly the class name and the properties with curly brackets and equal signs. It should just be **Mark,24,6**. How do I stop this from happening?

Below is an image of what's displayed in the dialogue window.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Current Result: Appointment{day=Mark,hour=24,name=6}

My Desired Result: `Mark,24,6`

The section that iterates through Appointment objects is below -

**button2 in FrontEnd.java**

```
for( Appointment a : list )
  {
      if ( a instanceof Appointment )
      appointments += a.toString() + "\n";
  }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, appointments);
```

```
public class MeetingCalendar 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
        IOException, NotSerializableException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        FrontEnd feframe = new FrontEnd();
        
        //Setup FrontEnd
        feframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        feframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        feframe.pack();
        feframe.setVisible(true);
       
        //setup file
        InputOutput.setupFile();
     
    }    
}
```

**Appointment.java (Model for record)**

```
public class Appointment implements Serializable
{
    private String day;
    private String hour;
    private String name;

    public Appointment(String day, String hour, String name) {
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(String hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Appointment{" + "day=" + day + ", hour=" + hour + ", name=" + name + '}';
    }
                
}
```

**FrontEnd.java**  -- this is where I believe the issue is at for( Appointment a : list )

```
public class FrontEnd extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JPanel pnlNorth, pnlSouth;
    public JButton button1, button2, btnHelp;
    
    public FrontEnd()
    {
        
        super("Meeting Calendar");
        
        pnlNorth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        pnlNorth.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

        JLabel welcomeLabel= new JLabel("Meeting Calendar",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
        welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 30)); 
        
        pnlNorth.add(welcomeLabel);
        pnlNorth.add(new JLabel("Enter or search Appointment:", SwingConstants.CENTER));
        
        button1 = new JButton("Add Appointment");
        
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        
        button2 = new JButton("Search Appointment");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

            {
                    String appointments = "";
 
                    ArrayList<Appointment> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                    list = InputOutput.readRecord("people.bin");
                    } catch (NotSerializableException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FrontEnd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FrontEnd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FrontEnd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    
                    for( Appointment a : list )
                    {
                        if ( a instanceof Appointment )
                        appointments += a.toString() + "\n";
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, appointments);
                }        
            });
        
        
        btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
        btnHelp.addActionListener(this);
        
        btnHelp.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello Help");
                }        
            });

        //Setup panel
       
        pnlSouth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        pnlSouth.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        
        pnlSouth.add(button1);
        pnlSouth.add(button2);
        
        pnlNorth.add(btnHelp);
        
        //get the container for the JFrame
        Container con = getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2,30));
        con.add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        con.add(pnlSouth, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  

    }  
    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        this.setVisible(false);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nNo lastname exists in records!\n");
        AddAppointment.createWindow();        
    }

}
```

**InputOutput.java**

```
public class InputOutput 
{
    
    public static void setupFile()
             throws FileNotFoundException, NotSerializableException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
          
        ArrayList<Appointment> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String file = "people.bin";

        File f = new File(file);
        
        if(f.exists())
        { 
            list = InputOutput.readRecord(file);
        }
        
    }
    
 
    public static void saveRecord(String fileName, ArrayList<Appointment> list)
        throws FileNotFoundException, NotSerializableException, IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fileoutstream = new FileOutputStream(fileName); 
        
        ObjectOutputStream objectoutstream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutstream);
        
        // write the arraylist of objects to file
        objectoutstream.writeObject(list);
        objectoutstream.close();
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Appointment> readRecord(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException, NotSerializableException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Appointment> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        
        // read the objects from the file and dump them into the arraylist
        list = (ArrayList<Appointment>)ois.readObject();
        
        ois.close();
        
        return list;
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrEmu.png
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. Presumably *you* wrote `Appointment#toString`, so can't you change that method? Alternatively you can create a `toNiceString` method and call that when you push onto `appointments`.

Comment: @Botje problem is we are reading binary file and its printing Appointment{day=Mark,hour=24,name=6} . I've uploaded screenshot. I only want Mark,24,6 printed.

Comment: Where you get the object from does not matter. Your dialog shows the output of  calling `Appointment#toString`, and you can clearly see how it constructs the result. Change the definition to the one you want.